# Receiving an error on terminal when pip installing magenta

Tags: python, tensorflow, magenta

When I `pip install magenta` in terminal, I receive an error and I don't really get how to solve it... The error is as follows:

`ERROR: tensorflow 2.3.0 has requirement gast==0.3.3, but you'll have gast 0.4.0 which is incompatible. ERROR: tensorflow 2.3.0 has requirement numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0, but you'll have numpy 1.19.1 which is incompatible. ERROR: tensorflow 2.3.0 has requirement scipy==1.4.1, but you'll have scipy 1.5.2 which is incompatible. ERROR: tensor2tensor 1.15.7 has requirement tensorflow-probability==0.7.0, but you'll have tensorflow-probability 0.11.0 which is incompatible. ERROR: note-seq 0.0.1 has requirement numba==0.48.0, but you'll have numba 0.49.1 which is incompatible. ERROR: apache-beam 2.23.0 has requirement dill<0.3.2,>=0.3.1.1, but you'll have dill 0.3.2 which is incompatible. ERROR: apache-beam 2.23.0 has requirement oauth2client<4,>=2.0.1, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.3 which is incompatible.`

I'm quite new to this stuff(stack overflow and coding) so any help would be much appreciated! I also apologise if there's something wrong with my post, please do let me know and I will correct it :)

Comment: It says you are too fancy! Joke, the versions you have installed are too new and not supported. Try `pip uninstall numba` and the same for all packages in the list, then try magenta again and pip will install the correct version of all of these

Comment: Yes, pip will automatically install/upgrade requirements, but it won't downgrade. FYI, you can manually install any version of a package like `pip install numpy==1.18.1`

Comment: I attempted this solution and happened to land on an error I missed out on, but when I reinstalled magenta I landed up with the same error so Im currently trying to uninstall these packages after reinstalling to see if it's any different. Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Try creating a new virtual environment and install whatever you need there to avoid version conflicts

Comment: Hey there! Yes I created a new env prior to attempting this

Comment: This issue was solved! Although a new problem showed up :( 
Reinstalling the required packages after installing magenta then installing magenta again after installing required packages removed these errors, thanks a lot @RichieV